# no route to host error 113

Tags: python, ftp, routes

If built a script which connects to an ftp server.I have tested it local on my pc and its working, but on the server it says: ***(113, 'No route to host').*** If i connect per shell with ***ftp XX.XX.XX.XX*** its working fine! This is how i try to connect in python:

```
            import ftplip
            meinftp = ftplib.FTP(ip)
            meinftp.login(user,password)
            meinftp.cwd(ftpdirectory)
```

Any ideas why i get no route to host? The firewall is not blocking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that strace is a good tool here, but it can be a bit daunting if you aren't familiar with it, or at least, familiar with C.

About use of strace and similar tools for debugging:
http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/debugging-with-syscall-tracers.html

Answer (score 1):

python returns 113 'No route to host' even if the DNS name is available, but the service is not working.

May be specific for FTP passive options.

Run your script with the 'strace' so you will be to check what syscall is failing.

strace -fo /tmp/log python yourscript.py

Answer (score 1):

See also https://stumbles.id.au/python-ftps-and-mis-configured-servers.html

Quoting: "I eventually noticed a message in the FileZilla logs, Server sent passive reply with unroutable address. Using server address instead. It turns out that the FTPS server was mis-configured and was replying to the PASV command with an internal IP address that was not accessible from the public internet. It seems that this is a common enough configuration issue that some FTP clients detect the problem and use the existing server address instead. Python's FTP client doesn't do this though."

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a firewall issue, try disabling the firewall.

Comment: Then i  couldnt connect in the console!

Comment: Its not possible for me to deactivate the firewall ! But the route in the firewall is free!